# Tricky geometry question

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $ABCD$ is a rhombus, and $M \in BC$, $N \in CD$. It is known that $AMN$ is an equilateral triangle. Find the angle $ABC$.

Comment: If it's a rhombus, $AB = BC = CD = AD$ anyway.

Comment: Diagrams, girls and boys: questions about geometry are **greatly enhanced** by a nice diagram!

Comment: For all rhombus such that BAD is greater than 60 degrees there is such a AMN  equilateral triangle.

Comment: Also, this seems underdetermined.  I can construct any number of rhombuses of different shapes that satisfy the conditions as I understand them.

Comment: @BrianTung Right, it was a typo, I meant BAD

Comment: ooo, problem title includes the word tricky: now I am just itching to spend a lot of time doing a lot of work to solve this question, and then write it all up here. I am a sucker for demands and unrewarding challenges yessir. Watch as I stumble over others and myself to write my greatest opus ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget the symmetric cases for a moment. Say (without loss of generality), $BM < CN$. Assume $M^* \in CD$ is the image of $M$ under reflection in diagonal $AC$. Then $MN$ is orthogonal to $AC$ and $AM^* = AM = AN = MN.$ Since $ABCD$ is a rhombus, $BD$ is perpendicular to $AC$ so $MM^*$ is parallel to $BD$. Now consider the circle $c_A$ centered at $A$ and of radius $AM$. Then $c_A$ goes through the points $M, \, N, \, M^*$. Then $$\angle \, MM^*N = \frac{1}{2} \, \angle \, MAN = \frac{1}{2} \, 60^{\circ} = 30^{\circ}$$. However, since $MM^*$ is parallel to $BD$
$$\angle \, BDC =  \angle \, MM^*N = 30^{\circ}$$ and since $ABCD$ is a rhombus,
$$\angle \, ABC = \angle \, CDA = 2 \, \angle BDC = 60^{\circ}$$

This is a bit rushed, but sounds more or less correct.

[image]